# How can I restart an GAE app engine version automatically every day?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Can you help me please
I can't find a way to restart GAE version
I would like to do a function which restarts a version every day in the morning

Comment: Why? What's your use case?

Comment: following instability of an app engine application
I received a request to automate the stop / start of a version
and it has to be done every day

Comment: You can try creating one or two Cloud Function which is/are triggered everyday and using the [GAE API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rpc#google.appengine.v1beta.instances) to start/stop(delete) your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you use App Engine standard, you don't have to worry about that because after a while without any request, the instance is offloaded automatically

If you use App Engine Flexible, the instance is restarted at least once a week. If you want to restart it, you can:

- Implement an endpoint that simply exit the app (`exit(0)`). After the exit the app engine will restart automatically. For that, you need to set the [max instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml#services) to 1. Indeed, if you have more than one instance, the stop request will stop only the instance that handle the request, not the others. In addition, that will cause outage for the existing requests.
- You can redeploy a new version of your application everyday. Use Cloud Scheduler to trigger a Cloud Build trigger that deploy the latest version.

---

In any case, to restart your app due to instability, memory leak or something else, is due to your code, not the platform. The platform isn't designed for  that, that's why it's not so simple to restart a service.